# Deprecating static class members in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have come across different macros which enable deprecation of member attributes and functions but none of them discuss the possibility of deprecating static class members.

I read that even in C++14 deprecation of static members is [not allowed](http://josephmansfield.uk/articles/marking-deprecated-c++14.html).

Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: Where would you suggest the warning should be emitted when a static member is deprecated?

Comment: C++14 actually has a [standard attribute for deprecation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) But why it is not possible to deprecate a static member is not clear to me.

Comment: @user975989 Would there be a problem to allow it at its declaration, i.e. in the class definition?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider My point is under which use cases should the warning be emitted? For example, if we deprecate static member `foo`, should the warning be emitted when we call a function with `foo` as argument? How about if we call a member function of `foo`. It just seems to me that emitting the warning for a deprecated function is a lot more clear cut than a class member.

Comment: @Note that iiuc you can very well deprecate non-static members, which would have the issues you mention (although I'm not sure I understand them all). I mean, you deprecate a member -- any time you use that member you get a warning. Static or not is just a semantic difference which is not interesting for determining whether a warning should be issued.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's get some facts:

The wording for the `[[deprecated]]` attribute is the following 
(*based on [N4269](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) 7.6.5 [dcl.attr.deprecated], emphasis mine*):

> 2. The attribute may be applied to the declaration of a class, a typedef-name, a **variable**, a **non-static data
>      member**, a **function**, a namespace, an enumeration, an enumerator, or a template specialization.

The misleading part is the explicit appearance of "non-static data members" without its counterpart at the same level in this list, but in that same list there are two other elements of interest.

- The description of a `variable` is (based on 3 [basic]) :

> 6. A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an
>      object. The variable’s name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

Which means that saying `a variable` includes static data members

- A `static member function` is a `function` (a red car is a car, this is a logical conclusion and i don't seem to find anything counter indicating this in the standard).
- There isn't any syntax or behaviour problem applying particularly to static members, a static function is pretty much a free function in a namespace and static data member is more or less a global variable in a namespace and you can deprecate free functions and global variables..
- As a bonus, it actually works in major compilers.

---

Summing up all this facts basically means that the `[[deprecated]]` attribute may actually be applied to a static data member, a non-static data member and a static member function, among other things.

So to answer your question, from my understanding, deprecating static members is actually allowed by the standard.